# dynamic generate table which accept input in multiple column and get rows total as well as overall total in angular 2

Tags: angular

Requirement is dynamic generate table which accept input in multiple column and get rows total as well as overall total in angular 2 like below

| column1 | column2 | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1-input1 | row1-input2 | row1-sum1 |
| row2-input1 | row2-input2 | row2-sum2 |
| total |  | sum of all rows of sum column |

Tried below static way but need some dynamic solution

````
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <th><input name="input1" type="number" [(ngModel)]="input1" ></th>
        <th><input name="input2" type="number" [(ngModel)]="input2" ></th>
        <th>{{input1 + input2}}</th>
      </tr>```

Please help
````

Answer (score 0):

you may store the values in the array, and sum the array at the end:

```html
<th *ngFor="let value of allValues">
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value" >
</th>
<th>{{sum}}</th>
```

```js
allValues = Array(100).fill(0);


get sum(): number {
   return this.allValues.reduce((a,c) => a + c, 0);
}
```